# How to loop function through list of aurguments in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to make this VBA function more dynamic and handle a list of inputs rather than a single static argument. The function I have is working correctly for a single hard coded file, I would like to make it loop through all files given specific criteria. The specific Criteria being: for each excel file in "C:\Sales_Reports\Special Promotions" with the name string starting with "2017 WK 9 WOW" (where the 9 could also be dynamic) call the function.

The function currently copies 18 values from file "2017 WK 9 WOW" without opening it into a consolidated workbook 'P' (where the macro is saved). I have several file "2017 WK 9 WOW"s that do not change in structure which all need to be copied to file 'P', adding a new row with the data each time (row 5, below header).

```
Sub GetVal()

    MsgBox TheValue("C:\Sales_Reports\Special Promotions", _
        "2017 WK 9 WOW - Ladies Tee", "Week Summary")
End Sub

Function TheValue(Path, WorkbookName, Sheet) As String
Dim testrange As Range
ActiveSheet.rows("5:5").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Set testrange = Range("d$15,e15,f15,t15,n15,s15,ab15,ae15,af15,aj15,ak15,am15,an15,ap15,aq15,at15,av15,bv6")

For Each cell In testrange

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
    Case "D15"
        TgtRng = "E"
    Case "E15"
        TgtRng = "F"
    Case "F15"
        TgtRng = "G"
    Case "T15"
        TgtRng = "H"
    Case "N15"
        TgtRng = "I"
    Case "S15"
        TgtRng = "J"
    Case "AB15"
        TgtRng = "K"
    Case "AE15"
        TgtRng = "L"
    Case "AF15"
        TgtRng = "M"
    Case "AJ15"
        TgtRng = "N"
    Case "AK15"
        TgtRng = "O"
    Case "AM15"
        TgtRng = "P"
    Case "AN15"
        TgtRng = "Q"
    Case "AP15"
        TgtRng = "R"
    Case "AQ15"
        TgtRng = "S"
    Case "AT15"
        TgtRng = "T"
    Case "AV15"
        TgtRng = "U"
    Case "BV6"
        TgtRng = "V"
    Case Else
        Exit Function

End Select

Range(TgtRng & "5").Value = "='" & Path & "\[" & WorkbookName & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & cell.Address

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next
End Function
```

Comment: 1. Function should

Comment: Few best practices: 1) Function should return a value (2) You can define a range object outside function pointing to the range to search and pass that object to function. (3) Replace select with range handling to identify the element number and derive the actual row number, don't hardcode it (4) Donot change cell value inside the function